# What is exact difference between mean filter and median filter

Tags: image-processing, filtering

I am trying to understand the c code of mean filter and median filter .
I understood the mean filter and implemented too .But for the median filter I am not able to understand the below logic used in one of the reference code for median filter .
I want to know why there is calculation of min and max in below example of median filter :

```
#define PAD_LINES 2
void ExecuteMedianFilterReference(cl_uint* p_input, cl_uint* p_output, cl_int width, cl_uint height)
{
    memset(p_output, 0,   width * (height+4));

    // do the Median
    for(cl_uint y = 0; y < height; y++)        // rows loop
    {
        int iOffset = (y+PAD_LINES) * width;
        int iPrev = iOffset - width;
        int iNext = iOffset + width;

        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)        // columns loop
        {
            unsigned uiRGBA[9];

            //get pixels within aperture
            uiRGBA[0] = p_input[iPrev + x - 1];
            uiRGBA[1] = p_input[iPrev + x];
            uiRGBA[2] = p_input[iPrev + x + 1];

            uiRGBA[3] = p_input[iOffset + x - 1];
            uiRGBA[4] = p_input[iOffset + x];
            uiRGBA[5] = p_input[iOffset + x + 1];

            uiRGBA[6] = p_input[iNext + x - 1];
            uiRGBA[7] = p_input[iNext + x];
            uiRGBA[8] = p_input[iNext + x + 1];

            unsigned uiMin = c4min(uiRGBA[0], uiRGBA[1]);
            unsigned uiMax = c4max(uiRGBA[0], uiRGBA[1]);
            uiRGBA[0] = uiMin;
            uiRGBA[1] = uiMax;

            uiMin = c4min(uiRGBA[3], uiRGBA[2]);
            uiMax = c4max(uiRGBA[3], uiRGBA[2]);
            uiRGBA[3] = uiMin;
            uiRGBA[2] = uiMax;

            uiMin = c4min(uiRGBA[2], uiRGBA[0]);
            uiMax = c4max(uiRGBA[2], uiRGBA[0]);
            uiRGBA[2] = uiMin;
            uiRGBA[0] = uiMax;

            uiMin = c4min(uiRGBA[3], uiRGBA[1]);
            uiMax = c4max(uiRGBA[3], uiRGBA[1]);
            uiRGBA[3] = uiMin;
            uiRGBA[1] = uiMax;

            uiMin = c4min(uiRGBA[1], uiRGBA[0]);
            uiMax = c4max(uiRGBA[1], uiRGBA[0]);
            uiRGBA[1] = uiMin;
            uiRGBA[0] = uiMax;

            uiMin = c4min(uiRGBA[3], uiRGBA[2]);
            uiMax = c4max(uiRGBA[3], uiRGBA[2]);
            uiRGBA[3] = uiMin;
            uiRGBA[2] = uiMax;

            uiMin = c4min(uiRGBA[5], uiRGBA[4]);
            uiMax = c4max(uiRGBA[5], uiRGBA[4]);
            uiRGBA[5] = uiMin;
            uiRGBA[4] = uiMax;

            uiMin = c4min(uiRGBA[7], uiRGBA[8]);
            uiMax = c4max(uiRGBA[7], uiRGBA[8]);
            uiRGBA[7] = uiMin;
            uiRGBA[8] = uiMax;

            uiMin = c4min(uiRGBA[6], uiRGBA[8]);
            uiMax = c4max(uiRGBA[6], uiRGBA[8]);
            uiRGBA[6] = uiMin;
            uiRGBA[8] = uiMax;

            uiMin = c4min(uiRGBA[6], uiRGBA[7]);
            uiMax = c4max(uiRGBA[6], uiRGBA[7]);
            uiRGBA[6] = uiMin;
            uiRGBA[7] = uiMax;

            uiMin = c4min(uiRGBA[4], uiRGBA[8]);
            uiMax = c4max(uiRGBA[4], uiRGBA[8]);
            uiRGBA[4] = uiMin;
            uiRGBA[8] = uiMax;

            uiMin = c4min(uiRGBA[4], uiRGBA[6]);
            uiMax = c4max(uiRGBA[4], uiRGBA[6]);
            uiRGBA[4] = uiMin;
            uiRGBA[6] = uiMax;

            uiMin = c4min(uiRGBA[5], uiRGBA[7]);
            uiMax = c4max(uiRGBA[5], uiRGBA[7]);
            uiRGBA[5] = uiMin;
            uiRGBA[7] = uiMax;

            uiMin = c4min(uiRGBA[4], uiRGBA[5]);
            uiMax = c4max(uiRGBA[4], uiRGBA[5]);
            uiRGBA[4] = uiMin;
            uiRGBA[5] = uiMax;

            uiMin = c4min(uiRGBA[6], uiRGBA[7]);
            uiMax = c4max(uiRGBA[6], uiRGBA[7]);
            uiRGBA[6] = uiMin;
            uiRGBA[7] = uiMax;

            uiMin = c4min(uiRGBA[0], uiRGBA[8]);
            uiMax = c4max(uiRGBA[0], uiRGBA[8]);
            uiRGBA[0] = uiMin;
            uiRGBA[8] = uiMax;

            uiRGBA[4] = c4max(uiRGBA[0], uiRGBA[4]);
            uiRGBA[5] = c4max(uiRGBA[1], uiRGBA[5]);

            uiRGBA[6] = c4max(uiRGBA[2], uiRGBA[6]);
            uiRGBA[7] = c4max(uiRGBA[3], uiRGBA[7]);

            uiRGBA[4] = c4min(uiRGBA[4], uiRGBA[6]);
            uiRGBA[5] = c4min(uiRGBA[5], uiRGBA[7]);

            // convert and copy to output
            p_output[(y+PAD_LINES) * width + x] = c4min(uiRGBA[4], uiRGBA[5]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though you've got OpenCL code from [Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/samples/median-filter) (or someplace similar). If you download the code sample from this link, the zip file includes a file called user_guide.pdf that explains the code in detail.

What it's doing is, for a 3x3 neighborhood, performing a partial bitonic sort on the elements. Normally, to find the median of a list of elements, you would sort the elements and find the one in the middle. So for example, if your list was

```
{6, 3, 9, 7, 4, 5, 8, 1, 2} <- 9 elements
```

you would sort it and get

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} <- middle is the 5th element
```

and the middle element would be `5`.

The partial sort allows you to find the median element without performing a complete sort, thereby performing fewer comparisons. I couldn't get the reference link in the pdf to work, but I did find a copy of the paper

> Frederick M. Waltz, Ralf Hack, and Bruce G. Batchelor. “Fast, efficient algorithms for 3x3 ranked filters using finite-state machines”.

[here](http://www-personal.engin.umd.umich.edu/~jwvm/ece581/18_RankedF.pdf). If you step through the execution of the program, it's sorting the first 4 elements in descending order, then sorting the last 5 elements in ascending order, then making swaps between the two sets to arrive at the median.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer.I was struggling to understand why there were min and max calculation and I got the answer as it is a bitonic sorting .

Answer (score 0):

The main idea of the median filter is to run through the signal entry by entry, replacing each entry with the median of neighboring entries. I am not able to able to understand the code completely as the details of all the methods are not provided, what i understood is it is taking a 3 X 3 window and somehow using min and max sorting it so that the median can be placed in the middle of the window.

A general pseudocode for the algorithm would be:
[image]

I would also recommend you to see the following link as it has implementation in various languages, can the logic can be understood easily.
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Median_filter